# How to get files in a directory, including all subdirectories

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a list of all log files (.log) in directory, including all subdirectories.

Comment: This has already been asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837606/find-the-oldest-file-recursively-in-a-directory, as well as a few others (search 'Python walk' in the search box)

Answer (score 132):

```
import os
import os.path

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("."):
    for filename in [f for f in filenames if f.endswith(".log")]:
        print os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
```

Comment: If you want to search in a different directory from "." you could pass the direcotry as sys.argv[1] and call os.walk(sys.argv[1]).

Comment: Additional improvement: Use a generator instead of list comprehension: for filename in (f for f ...)

Comment: If you want to exclude a certain directory, e.g., `old_logs`, you can simply remove it from `dirnames` and it won't be searched: `if "old_logs" in dirnames: dirnames.remove("old_logs")`

Comment: Any faster method, like using multiprocessing.Pool() or something?

Comment: Since Python 3 print is a function and must be called like this: `print(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))`

Answer (score 23):

You can also use the glob module along with os.walk.

```
import os
from glob import glob

files = []
start_dir = os.getcwd()
pattern   = "*.log"

for dir,_,_ in os.walk(start_dir):
    files.extend(glob(os.path.join(dir,pattern)))
```

Comment: What do the underscores do in the for-loop? '_'

Comment: @nueverest `os.walk` returns a 3-tuple `(dirpath, dirnames, filenames)` at each iteration, and we're only interested in `dirpath` (assigned to `dir` above); the underscores are just used as placeholders for the other 2 values we're not interested in (i.e. `dirnames`, and then `filenames`, are being assigned to the variable `_`, which we will never use).

Comment: Why run `glob` and do extra I/O, when you already have the list of `filenames` which you could filter with [`fnmatch.filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.filter)?

Comment: This redefines the `dir` function, use `for directory,_,_ ...` instead.

Answer (score 8):

Checkout [Python Recursive Directory Walker](http://ssscripting.wordpress.com/2009/03/03/python-recursive-directory-walker/). In short os.listdir() and os.walk() are your friends.

Answer (score 5):

A single line solution using only (nested) list comprehension:

```
import os

path_list = [os.path.join(dirpath,filename) for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk('.') for filename in filenames if filename.endswith('.log')]
```

Comment: This "one-liner" is excessive. If you're going over 79 characters (see [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length)), it takes away from readability and should either be split into multiple lines or made into a function (preferred).

Comment: That's true, I posted this mostly for the simplicity & list comprehension. It's indeed nice to split this over multiple lines.

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution:

```
import os
for logfile in os.popen('find . -type f -name *.log').read().split('\n')[0:-1]:
      print logfile
```

or

```
import subprocess
(out, err) = subprocess.Popen(["find", ".", "-type", "f", "-name", "*.log"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
for logfile in out.split('\n')[0:-1]:
  print logfile
```

These two take the advantage of `find . -type f -name *.log`.

The first one is simpler but not guaranteed 
for white-space when add `-name *.log`, 
but worked fine for simply `find ../testdata -type f` 
(in my OS X environment).

The second one using subprocess seems more complicated, but this is the white-space safe one (again, in my OS X environment).

This is inspired by Chris Bunch, 
in the answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3503909/2834102

Answer (score 1):

Using standard library's `pathlib`:

```
from pathlib import Path

working_dir = Path()
for path in working_dir.glob("**/*.log"):
    print(path)
    # OR if you need absolute paths
    print(path.absolute())
    # OR if you need only filenames without extension for further parsing
    print(path.stem)
```

Answer (score -1):

If You want to list in current directory, You can use something like:

```
import os

for e in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    print e
```

Just change the

```
os.getcwd()
```

to other path to get results there.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the OP's question and isn't relevant to most people who would be seeking the same answer.