# Assign output of os.system to a variable and prevent it from being displayed on the screen

Tags: python

I want to assign the output of a command I run using `os.system` to a variable and prevent it from being output to the screen. But, in the below code ,the output is sent to the screen and the value printed for `var` is 0, which I guess signifies whether the command ran successfully or not. Is there any way to assign the command output to the variable and also stop it from being displayed on the screen?

```
var = os.system("cat /etc/services")
print var #Prints 0
```

Comment: Don't use `os.system` (nor `os.popen`, per the answer you accepted): use `subprocess.Popen`, it's _way_ better!

Comment: @AlexMartelli, one can't use a complex commands (e.g. piped) in subprocess.Popen(), but with os.system one can

Comment: @vak, of course you can use pipes &c w/`subprocess.Popen` -- just add `shell=True`!

Comment: @AlexMartelli `shell=True` is (generally) a very bad idea! You have to be very sure of what you're executing :)

Comment: @AlexMartelli it's not useful to say that something is "way better" without saying why.

Comment: @user650261, as is pretty obvious as soon as you look into os.system, os.popen, and subprocess.Popen, the latter gives you far more fine-grained control. That clearly will be "way better" if you need something different than the simpler approaches' behavior, as the OP evidently does.

Comment: @IgnacioFernández, os.open and os.popen require exactly the same degree of certainty about what you're executing as subprocess.Popen with shell=True, so that's absolutely no reason to avoid the latter.

Comment: @AlexMartelli this is Stack Overflow, where the goal is to provide that type of information to people asking questions rather than telling them to rtm.  Even now, it is not clear what fine-grained control is more useful for OP's case.

Answer (score 652, accepted):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410976/equivalent-of-backticks-in-python) which I asked a long time ago, what you may want to use is `popen`:

```
os.popen('cat /etc/services').read()
```

From the [docs for Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#os.popen),

> This is implemented using subprocess.Popen; see that class’s
> documentation for more powerful ways to manage and communicate with
> subprocesses.

---

Here's the corresponding code for `subprocess`:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(["cat", "/etc/services"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(out, err) = proc.communicate()
print("program output:", out)
```

Comment: Note that Walter's `subprocess.check_output` solution is closer to the Pythonic one-liner it seems you're looking for, as long as you don't care about `stderr`.

Comment: @ChrisBunch Why is suprocess a better solution than `os.popen`?

Comment: You should (almost) never use `shell=True`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerationshttps://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations

Comment: what is the difference between os.Popen and subprocess.popen?

Comment: Good answer! Question though: Why in this example is `stdout=PIPE` specified, but not `stderr=PIPE` too? In example I see: `((out, err) = proc.communicate()` to capture both stdout and stderr, but if you don't use `stderr=PIPE`, will `err` ever get populated? Intentional or typo?

Comment: Is it a good idea to close this open pipe at any point? Or should we just leave it because it's not taking up an resources?

Comment: I keep coming across this and every time I wonder - why is it better to have three lines of complicated code rather than one line of obvious code?

Comment: Not only should you (almost) never use `shell=True`, but it's also incorrect in this case. `shell=True` makes the _shell_ the child process rather than `cat`, so `out` and `err` are the stdout/stderr of the _shell_ process rather than of the `cat` process

Comment: python retains the '\n' at the end so you probably want to strip that if you want exact compatability.

Comment: How can we avoid to remove '\n'. I am facing this prob now

Comment: catching into variable seems to be more convenient in understanding in first glance like, 

**output = os.popen('ls').read()**

Comment: @Ant6n is it better to try to slice a stick of butter with the flat side of a knife or the edge? Is it better to try to squish a stick of butter with the flat side of a knife, or the edge? Is it better to write two simple wrappers around a single, complex implementation of "knife", or is it better to create multiple implementations of the complex system, duplicating code and errors, and create a 1:1 mapping between simple interfaces at every level? -- This last question definitely gets a "no" -- the knife is an efficient construct, and the range of interactions is complex to specify.

Comment: Should add .rstrip() at the end to remove the extra line added by popen

Comment: If you want to execute a shell script with popen(), you must run the 'sh' command. E.g. subprocess.Popen(["/bin/sh", "/home/user/myscript", .....]

Answer (score 238):

You might also want to look at the `subprocess` module, which was built to replace the whole family of Python `popen`-type calls.

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output("cat /etc/services", shell=True)
```

The advantage it has is that there is a ton of flexibility with how you invoke commands, where the standard in/out/error streams are connected, etc.

Comment: note, `check_output` was added with python 2.7 https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Comment: Add `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` to capture standard errors as well

Comment: i used this method with ***systeminfo*** command.                                             Output was something ***nasty*** like this ```b'\r\nHost Name:                 DIMUTH-LAPTOP\r\nOS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro\r\nOS Version:                10.0.10240 N/A Build 10240\r\nOS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation```

Comment: how can i print in line by line . because above output is a mess

Comment: @ghost21blade found a solution?

Comment: @otto Not yet !!

Comment: @ghost21blade, you might want to look into this: `output.decode("utf-8").split("\n")` or whatever you´d like to do with it. You must convert it [into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string) first!

Answer (score 48):

The commands module is a reasonably high-level way to do this:

```
import commands
status, output = commands.getstatusoutput("cat /etc/services")
```

status is 0, output is the contents of /etc/services.

Comment: Quoting from the [documentation of the commands module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html#commands): *"Deprecated since version 2.6: The commands module has been removed in Python 3. Use the subprocess module instead."*.

Comment: sure it's outdated but sometimes you just want to get something done quickly and easily in a few lines of code.

Comment: @advocate check out the check_output command of subprocess. It's quick, easy, and won't depreciate soon!

Answer (score 43):

For python 3.5+ it is recommended that you use the [run function from the subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run). This returns a `CompletedProcess` object, from which you can easily obtain the output as well as return code. Since you are only interested in the output, you can write a utility wrapper like this.

```
from subprocess import PIPE, run

def out(command):
    result = run(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True, shell=True)
    return result.stdout

my_output = out("echo hello world")
# Or
my_output = out(["echo", "hello world"])
```

Comment: Dont forget "capture_output=True" option for run()

Comment: Using:
`result = run(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True, shell=True, capture_output=True)`

with capture_output injected returns:

`ValueError: stdout and stderr arguments may not be used with capture_output.`

Answer (score 35):

I know this has already been answered, but I wanted to share a potentially better looking way to call Popen via the use of `from x import x` and functions:

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen


def cmdline(command):
    process = Popen(
        args=command,
        stdout=PIPE,
        shell=True
    )
    return process.communicate()[0]

print cmdline("cat /etc/services")
print cmdline('ls')
print cmdline('rpm -qa | grep "php"')
print cmdline('nslookup google.com')
```

Comment: 3 years later, this is what worked for me. I threw this in a separate file called `cmd.py`, and then in my main file I wrote `from cmd import cmdline` and used it as needed.

Comment: I was getting the same issue with os.system returning 0, but I tried this method and it works great! And as a bonus it looks nice and tidy :) Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I do it with `os.system` temp file:

```
import tempfile, os

def readcmd(cmd):
    ftmp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.out', prefix='tmp', delete=False)
    fpath = ftmp.name
    if os.name=="nt":
        fpath = fpath.replace("/","\\") # forwin
    ftmp.close()
    os.system(cmd + " > " + fpath)
    data = ""
    with open(fpath, 'r') as file:
        data = file.read()
        file.close()
    os.remove(fpath)
    return data
```

Answer (score 3):

Python 2.6 and 3 specifically say to avoid using PIPE for stdout and stderr.

The correct way is

```
import subprocess

# must create a file object to store the output. Here we are getting
# the ssid we are connected to
outfile = open('/tmp/ssid', 'w');
status = subprocess.Popen(["iwgetid"], bufsize=0, stdout=outfile)
outfile.close()

# now operate on the file
```

Answer (score -1):

````py
from os import system, remove
from uuid import uuid4

def bash_(shell_command: str) -> tuple:
    """

    :param shell_command: your shell command
    :return: ( 1 | 0, stdout)
    """

    logfile: str = '/tmp/%s' % uuid4().hex
    err: int = system('%s &> %s' % (shell_command, logfile))
    out: str = open(logfile, 'r').read()
    remove(logfile)
    return err, out

# Example: 
print(bash_('cat /usr/bin/vi | wc -l'))
>>> (0, '3296\n')```
````