# How to convert byte array to string in bash code Linux

Tags: c#, linux, bash, encoding, byte

I`m trying to find equivalent code in bash (Linux) to C# code.

I have this C# code:

```
// C# to convert a byte array to a string.
byte [] dBytes = ...
string str;
System.Text.UTF8Encoding enc = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
str = enc.GetString(dBytes);
```

I'm running bash on fedora Linux machine.

I`m getting in bash a file containg all the byte array as text seperated by whitespace like this:

"72 0 101 0 108 0 108 0 111 0 32 0 87 0 111 0 114 0 108 0 100 0 33 0"

any ideas?

Comment: I think you should publish a short extract of your file that you're trying to read

Comment: Just a random thought: if you have C# code that is working - have you considered using Mono? It sounds like you are trying to convert this to bash: what have you tried?

Comment: +1 to Marc's suggestion. Another random thought, if you are running on Linux, you have the runtimes for a number of programming languages by default, that you don't get with Windows. You [could do this really easily with python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/606199/969613), and then [run the Python script from Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4377147/969613). Just a thought!

Comment: i already have a script in bash and i need to add another function to it that can do this

Comment: I suppose python could work, i tried to avoid it so the entire code will be in one script but if there is no way to accomplish this in bash...

Answer (score 0):

Eventually i did it in python and called the python script from my bash script:

```
file = open('xx.txt', 'r')
inputText = file.read()
split = inputText.split(" ")
noZeros= filter (lambda a: a != "0", split)
results = map(int, noZeros)
final = "".join(map(chr, results))
print final
```

Answer (score 0):

Those bytes are in UTF-16LE encoding, not UTF-8. Your python script should just be:

```
file = codecs.open('xx.txt', 'r', 'utf-16-le')
ustring = file.read() #this is a unicode string, not a normal python string
print ustring
```