# Python: need to use bash one-liner

Tags: python, linux, cpu

I'm trying to write a script to help my company with some of our investigations. I can't install any extra packages on the systems and I need to be able to get the current processor load total in percentage.

So far I can't find any native python module that allows this so I am trying to use a bash command:
ps aux|awk 'NR > 0{s +=$3};END{print "CPU %",s}'

I have been trying it in os.system and os.popen and I can't seem to get it to execute properly.

```
import os, multiprocessing
p = os.system("ps aux|awk 'NR > 0 { s +=$3 }; END {print "cpu %",s}'")
print "Cores:", multiprocessing.cpu_count(), '\nCPU Load:', p
```

I could use a hint or two. I know you're supposed to separate the command and args with a ',' in os.system but I have tried and I can't seem to get it to work. Does anyone know of a better way to execute a long one-liner in Python?

I am new to python and appreciate any answers given. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
import os, multiprocessing
p = os.popen("ps aux|awk 'NR > 0 { s +=$3 }; END {print s}'").read().rstrip("\n")
print "Cores:", multiprocessing.cpu_count(), '\nCPU Load:', p, "%"
```

gives

```
Cores: 4
CPU Load: 5.1 %
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you.  Both were great answers, though.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there: just needed to "escape" the quotes ( i.e. use `print \"` instead of `print "` , etc) to get the first line right:

```
import os, multiprocessing
p = os.system("ps aux|awk 'NR > 0 { s +=$3 }; END {print \"cpu %\",s}'")
```

And you should recognize that the `os.system` command returns the "return code" - the answer to the question "did this process end normally?". Thus the value of `p` is `0` "no error", not the cpu load which was in the variable `s`. Not sure why you need it twice since you already printed it out. Change the last line to

```
print "Cores:", multiprocessing.cpu_count(), '\n'
```

And the output becomes something like:

```
cpu% 65.7
Cores: 2
```

If you actually want to get the output of your system command straight into a variable, you could look at the answer given to [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503879/assign-output-of-os-system-to-a-variable-and-prevent-it-from-being-displayed-on) - it shows you how to use `subprocess.Popen()` and `proc.communicate()` to do exactly that. But just getting the command line right (with the escaped quote) is the most critical fix.

**update** two complete and working examples of the Popen() and system() methods follow:

```
import os, multiprocessing, subprocess
# two ways to get CPU load and number of CPUs

# command line string to obtain CPU load:
commandString = "ps aux|awk 'NR > 0 { s+=$3 }; END {print \"CPU%\", s}'"
print "Command string used to obtain CPU load:"
print commandString, "\n"

# obtain number of CPUs from the multiprocessing function:
numCPUs = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

# method 1: issue an os.system command, have the result echoed directly to output:
print "Method 1:"
p = os.system(commandString)
print "Cores:", numCPUs, "\n"

# method 2: return the value to a python variable:
cpu = subprocess.Popen(commandString, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(out, err) = cpu.communicate()
print "Method 2:"
print "Load: ", out,
print "Cores:", multiprocessing.cpu_count(), '\n'
```

Output of the above:

```
Command string used to obtain CPU load:
ps aux|awk 'NR > 0 { s+=$3 }; END {print "CPU%", s}' 

Method 1:
CPU% 18.5
Cores: 2 

Method 2:
Load:  CPU% 24.1
Cores: 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still not working, though. 
I looked at that post and modified my script:
 `import subprocess, multiprocessing
    cpu = subprocess.Popen(["ps aux|awk 'NR > 0{s +=$3;END{print \"CPU %\",s'"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    (out, err) = cpu.communicate()
    print "Cores:" multiprocessing.cpu.count(), '\n'
    print "Load", out`

I am still getting errors. It is coming back with "unexpected newline or end of string" at the second 's'.

Thanks for the escaped quote. Didn't think about that. :)

Comment: There are several typos in your command: you are opening `{` and not closing them... I have updated my answer "for completeness" - note that by putting the command string in its own variable you see the difference between the two calls more clearly.