# Get control over an external process into current python program?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have an executable `xyz.exe` that is purely driven by command prompt/shell. It interactively takes input and displays output. Assume `xyz.exe` is somewhat like the typical python shell on windows. It waits for user to type something `>>>` and thereby proceeds to process the input.

Now, I want to get control over this `xyz.exe` process and bring it entirely into the context of my current python console/shell. How can I do this?

I referred [Assign output of os.system to a variable and prevent it from being displayed on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503879/assign-output-of-os-system-to-a-variable-and-prevent-it-from-being-displayed-on) and tried doing the same using subprocess:

```
import subprocess

cmd = r"\\sharedLocation\path\xyz.exe"
proc = subprocess.Popen([cmd], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(out, err) = proc.communicate()
print("program output:", out)
```

but that only gets the immediate (first time) output of `xyz.exe` when it starts, more like the welcome message. But after the first time output/welcome message, the `xyz.exe` actually waits for user input `">>>"`... I want my current execution of the python script to `wait()` and bring-in the entire context of `xyz.exe` inside the scope of my script output. Is there a way to do this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, whatever you input will be fed to `xyz.exe` but you won't see any further messages as `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` has been passed to Popen's constructor, which will make the output of the command not be  outputted; instead it is fed to the file-like `proc.stdout`. The welcome message is printed because of `print("program output:", out)`. To make the output of `xyz.exe` show up in the console remove `stdout=subprocess.PIPE,` from the Popen constructor arguments. Then `print("program output:", out)` is unnecessary.