# Copying the contents of a variable to the clipboard

Tags: python

I am trying to copy the contents of a variable to the clipboard automatically within a python script. So, a variable is created that holds a string, and I'd like to copy that string to the clipboard.

Is there a way to do this with Pyclips or

```
os.system("echo '' | pbcopy")
```

I've tried passing the variable where the string should go, but that doesn't work which makes sense to me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
import os
def addToClipBoard(text):
    command = 'echo ' + text.strip() + '| clip'
    os.system(command)
```

Read more solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579687/how-do-i-copy-a-string-to-the-clipboard-on-windows-using-python).

**Edit:**

You may call it as:

```
addToClipBoard(your_variable)
```

Comment: If your variable is a string, you must pass it to the function: `addToClipBoard(var)`

Comment: I had to change ' | clip' to ' | pbcopy', otherwise it wouldn't copy to the clipboard. Was this a mistake, or is there a reason?

Comment: I'm not totally sure, but I think it depends on the OS you are using. Are you using a Mac? See this: http://superuser.com/a/124282

Comment: Yep, I'm using a Mac.

Comment: This is a OS specific answer, not a Python answer.

Comment: If you are on the command line, on the python debugger (pdb), the one-liner version might come in handy: `import os; def addToClipBoard(text): command = 'echo ' + text.strip() + '| clip'; os.system(command)`

Answer (score 19):

Since you mentioned PyCLIPS, it sounds like 3rd-party packages are on the table. Let me thrown a recommendation for [pyperclip](https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip). Full documentation can be found on GitHub, but here's an example:

```
import pyperclip
variable = 'Some really "complex" string with\na bunch of stuff in it.'
pyperclip.copy(variable)
```

While the `os.system(...'| pbcopy')` examples are also good, they could give you trouble with complex strings and pyperclip provides the same API cross-platform.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer was not working for me as the output had quotes, apostrophes and $$ signs which were interpreted and replaced by the shell.

I've improved the function based on answer. This solution uses temporary file instead of echoing the string in the shell.

```
def add_to_clipboard(text):
    import tempfile
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile("w") as fp:
        fp.write(text)
        fp.flush()
        command = "pbcopy < {}".format(fp.name)
        os.system(command)
```

Replace the `pbcopy` with `clip` for Windows or `xclip` for Linux.

Comment: This answer worked best for me as well, as newlines cause issues. Helpful when what you're trying to copy is to large to grab from the print screen

Comment: Changing to `command = "xclip -sel clip {}".format(fp.name)` worked for me on Linux

Answer (score 3):

For X11 (Unix/Linux):

```
os.system('echo "%s" | xsel -i' % variable)
```

[xsel](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xsel) also gives you a choice of writing to:

1. the primary selection (default)
2. the secondary selection (`-s` option), or
3. the clipboard (`-b` option).

If `xsel` doesn't work as you expect, it is probably because you are using the wrong selection/clipboard.

In addition, with the `-a` option, you can append to the clipboard instead of overwrite.  With `-c`, the clipboard is cleared.

#### Improvement

The module `subprocess` provides a more secure way to do the same thing:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
Popen(('xsel', '-i'), stdin=PIPE).communicate(variable)
```

Comment: Also, look into `subprocess` module, it's what finally got me working with the pipe. I can only recommend http://stackoverflow.com/a/23796709/266446 and using -b for xsel is also a good idea as it gets the `variable` into your clipboard..like the one you have normally in desktop and stuff. (I've only find there are a lot of clipboards in Linux reading about this `xsel` and its cousin `xclip`.

Comment: @Huge Good suggestion.  I just updated the answer to show `subprocess` and include mention of the `-b` option.