# Python Jupyter: Shortcut to copy output of a cell

Tags: python, jupyter

Please see attached screenshot:[image]

In Jupyter Python: Is there a shortcut to copy the *output* of a cell to clipboard? (ie without having to manually select and ctrl-c?)

Alternatively is there a python function that instead of print would return its output directly in the clipboard for it to be pasted later?

Comment: Maybe this solution is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20821815/copying-the-contents-of-a-variable-to-the-clipboard

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610889/how-to-copy-paste-dataframe-from-stackoverflow-into-python

Answer (score 8):

You may use the following piece of code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['Copy me to clipboard'])
df.to_clipboard(index=False,header=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

what i have done is ---file -->Print Preview , it opens the whole output in another tab than you can copy whatever you want