# How to return a value using a C file, then pick it up in python using the os.system?

Tags: python, c, linux, return, os.system

I'm using the the python os.system to print a value received from a C file.

My C file says...

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() 
{
printf("hello world\n");
return 7;
}
```

Then I have a python file which does the following...

```
import os

x = os.system("./a.out")

print x
```

When I run the python program on a linux command line, I get "hello world" successfully printed, but the variable x is printed as 1792.

I want x to be printed as 7, not 1792. Why is x being printed as 1792 and how do I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assign output of os.system to a variable and prevent it from being displayed on the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503879/assign-output-of-os-system-to-a-variable-and-prevent-it-from-being-displayed-on)

Comment: You could be right. I'm checking out the solution there to see if my question is useless.

Comment: @Emilien No, that is talking about a related, but different, task (capturing the *output* of a program, not its exit code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`os.system` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system):

> On Unix, the return value is the exit status of the process encoded in
>   the format specified for `wait()`. Note that POSIX does not specify the
>   meaning of the return value of the C system() function, so the return
>   value of the Python function is system-dependent.

Use [`os.WEXITSTATUS`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.WEXITSTATUS) to get the return code:

```
import os
x = os.system("./a.out")
print os.WEXITSTATUS(x)
```

Comment: @Alex So you prefer to stick with old, deprecated methods like `os.system()` instead of the preferred `subprocess`? Your choice, but don't say you haven't been warned.

Comment: @glglgl Well it depends what the disadvantages are.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers about `os.WEXITSTATUS` are correct, but the recommended way to do this is with [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html). The documentation for [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) includes the following paragraph:

> The [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function. See the [Replacing Older Functions with the `subprocess` Module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements) section in the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) documentation for some helpful recipes.

Since you are interested in the return code, you can use [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call):

```
import subprocess

x = subprocess.call(['./a.out'])

print x
```

Answer (score 1):

The value returned from `os.system` is a *wait status*, which contains an encoding of the value returned by the program, plus other information.  You decode it with [`os.WIFEXITED`, `os.WEXITSTATUS`, and their relatives](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.WCOREDUMP).

```
>>> import os
>>> x = os.system("exit 7")
>>> x
1792
>>> os.WIFEXITED(x)
True
>>> os.WEXITSTATUS(x)
7
```

Two additional details you need to know are: If the value returned from `main` (or passed to `exit`) is negative or greater than 255, it will be truncated.  If `os.WIFEXITED(x)` is false, `os.WEXITSTATUS(x)` is garbage.