# QLineEdit.setText(QString): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'

Tags: java, python, pyqt, int

So i made this little program that's supposed to tell you the java version but i got this error :

> QLineEdit.setText(QString): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'

while trying to run it

the code :

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *


class java(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def s(self):
        g = os.system("java -version")
        self.version.setText(g)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(java, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setMinimumSize(201, 82)
        self.setMaximumSize(201, 82)

        self.version = QLineEdit(self)
        self.version.setMinimumSize(181, 21)
        self.version.setMaximumSize(181, 21)
        self.version.setGeometry(QRect(10 ,10, self.width(), self.height()))

        self.fetch = QPushButton(self)
        self.fetch.setMinimumSize(181, 23)
        self.fetch.setMaximumSize(181, 23)
        self.fetch.setGeometry(QRect(10, 50, self.width(), self.height()))
        self.fetch.setText("Fetch version")

        self.fetch.clicked.connect(self.s)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = java()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: If you would have made a minimal example you have seen that the output of os.system calls is not a string yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your method `s`, wherein you execute the `os.system` call.

```
def s(self):
    g = os.system("java -version")
    self.version.setText(g)
```

The variable `g` here stores `True` or `False`, which is the output of the system call, and not the version of java

To capture the outputted version, use subprocess module, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3504154/1860929)