# Searching over 20,000+ files in network driver. Glob is slow. Command line gives error

Tags: python, python-2.7, search

I need search a file from network driver (the folder contains twenty thousand or more files)

I tried use `glob` to search but is very slow. It usually needs 50s~60s to complete the search.

```
path = r'\\network\driver\'
file = '12AC9K-XXE-849*'
print(glob.glob(path+file))
```

I also tried use command line tools (all system is in Windows):

```
os.chdir(path)
print(os.system("dir 12AC9K-XXE-849*"))
```

I think the issues are in the network so I can not use `cmd.exe` because I will get the error message:

```
'\\network\driver\'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Thanks tdelaney

finally i find answer and get "dir" value.

use subprocess

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(["dir/b", "\\network\driver\12AC9K-XXE-849*"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(out, err) = proc.communicate()
out = out.splitlines()
print out
```

[get dir value anwser](http://Thanks%20tdelaney%20%20finally%20i%20find%20answer%20and%20get%20%22dir%22%20value.%20%20use%20subprocess%20%20import%20subprocess%20%20proc%20=%20subprocess.Popen([%22dir/b%22,%20%22%5C%5Cnetwork%5Cdriver%5C12AC9K-XXE-849*%22],%20stdout=subprocess.PIPE,%20shell=True)%20(out,%20err)%20=%20proc.communicate()%20out%20=%20out.splitlines()%20print%20out%20%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503879/assign-output-of-os-system-to-a-variable-and-prevent-it-from-being-displayed-on)

thanks all help

Comment: How long does it take at the command line?

Comment: command line only need 1 or 2 second can find the file

Comment: In the second case do `os.system(r"dir \\network\driver\12AC9K-XXE-849*")` to avoid the path problem.

Comment: I'm curious (and lacking a Windows machine w/ an ntfs share) how `os.listdir(path)` compares to glob. Is it about the same time?