# Python 3.5 CGI os.system command get the output to a variable to display later in a browser

Tags: python-3.x, cgi

I am new to Python, so any pointers are highly appreciated. I am running os.system("multiple commands here") but I am unable to get the output to a variable to display later. Also I am writing CGI script.

Here is what I am trying:

I am passing the IP variable which I am taking as input from user.

os.system("/usr/local/bin/nmap %s (ip)| grep tcp | awk -F '/' '{print $1}' ")

in bash this would be like

var=$(os.system("/usr/local/bin/nmap %s (ip)| grep tcp | awk -F '/' '{print $1}' "))

echo $var.

I want to do the same in Python 3.5 to echo this out on a browser.

I tried the os.popen approach but it errors out when I pass variable to it and
I need to be able to pass variable in the command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign output of os.system to a variable and prevent it from being displayed on the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503879/assign-output-of-os-system-to-a-variable-and-prevent-it-from-being-displayed-on)