# Conversion of linux command into Python 3.5.2

Tags: linux, python-3.x, grep

Hey guys I have a question, in my linux I usually grep something in file and print output or print count, How can I do the same in python script.
For e.g

```
Linux Command : grep name filename.txt | wc -l

Python 3.5.2 Command : os.system("grep name filename.txt | wc -l")
```

This gives me exact result as of linux command, but I need to store this in variable and then print how can I achieve that.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503879/assign-output-of-os-system-to-a-variable-and-prevent-it-from-being-displayed-on

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call external programs, this would do the equivalent of your command:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('name')
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    count = sum(bool(pattern.search(line)) for line in f)
print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
command1 : grep name filename.txt 
command2 : wc -l
```

The output of command 1 will be the input for command 2

Syntax in python:

```
first_output = subprocess.Popen(command 1, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
second_output = subprocess.Popen(command 2,stdin=first_output.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = second_output.communicate()
```

Example -

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen("grep name filename.txt", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen("wc -l",stdin=p1.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p2.communicate()
```

- out - output of p2 in text format
- err - error log, if any