# How to show os.system() in textEdit in pyqt4

Tags: linux, python-2.7, pyqt4, qtextedit, pyuic

I use QtDesigner and pyqt4 for design my application.
I want to show os.system() function results in textEdit!
here is my code:

```
def aiaa(self):
    import os
    ss = os.system("systemctl status tor.service")
    self.textEdit.setText(str(ss))
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 10, 351, 201))
    self.textEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit"))
    self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 250, 94, 32))
    self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.aiaa)
```

but its show result in terminal not in textEdit.
Thanks...

Comment: you can't with `os.system`. See [Assign output of os.system to a variable and prevent it from being displayed on the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503879/assign-output-of-os-system-to-a-variable-and-prevent-it-from-being-displayed-on)

Comment: Thanks @fredtantini

Answer (score 0):

The reason your example won't work is because `os.system` returns the exit code of the command, rather than its output (which is just printed on stdout). There are [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3503879/984421) which give some standard python solutions for this, but since you are using PyQt. I thought I'd show the Qt way of doing things instead.

Below is a demo script that uses a `QProcess` to run commands. Signals from the process are connected to some slots which can then display the output from stdout and stderr whenever they become available:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.display = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
        self.display.setReadOnly(True)
        self.command = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Run Command', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.display)
        layout.addWidget(self.command)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.process = QtCore.QProcess(self)
        self.process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.handleStdOut)
        self.process.readyReadStandardError.connect(self.handleStdErr)

    def handleButton(self):
        self.process.start(self.command.text())

    def handleStdOut(self):
        data = self.process.readAllStandardOutput().data()
        self.display.append(data.decode('utf-8'))

    def handleStdErr(self):
        data = self.process.readAllStandardError().data()
        self.display.append(data.decode('utf-8'))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 500, 400)
    window.command.setText('systemctl status tor.service')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks it's Worked!:D

Comment: @amirrezaw. Great! If you found the answer useful, please accept it (i.e. click on the tick synbol).