# Get wget output in python variable

Tags: python, wget, openwrt

I am able to download the file using wget and I can see the progress in the console, But how can we store this output into a python variable ?.

a sample code give below, I am excepting something like this.

```
output = os.popen('wget https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python3_tutorial.pdf')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign output of os.system to a variable and prevent it from being displayed on the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503879/assign-output-of-os-system-to-a-variable-and-prevent-it-from-being-displayed-on)

Comment: @ Peter Wood,wget result is different than other os command results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you can catch stdout of programs with subprocess

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output('ping localhost', stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

Comment: @Arun That's [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3504154/1084416) on the linked duplicate

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend using wget, use urllib instead: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html.

If you must use wget just read the output file after wget writes it.

```
os.system('wget https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python3_tutorial.pdf -O your_file_path')
print open('your_file_path').read()
```