# Run command line in python and save the details

Tags: python, operating-system, command-line-tool

i am trying to run some command line in python script, like:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

and when i write this code:

```
import os
os.system('ping 8.8.8.8')
```

it printing me the details of the command.
but i want it for be background command,
what mean i dont want to user will see all the details.
i want to save it to varilble, and after that edit and print as my wish.
how can i do that?
i try to store what the function return, as:

```
answer = os.system('ping 8.8.8.8')
```

but the function return 0. help someone?

Comment: use `subprocess.check_output()` instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign output of os.system to a variable and prevent it from being displayed on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503879/assign-output-of-os-system-to-a-variable-and-prevent-it-from-being-displayed-on)

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a bat file with ping 8.8.8.8 written in it.
Then you can use the subprocess command to invoke it from within the python script.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('ping.bat')
```

Comment: You cannot call the module that you import

Comment: Edited it. Now you may remove your downvote. @Anthon

Answer (score 0):

`import os
res = os.popen('ping 8.8.8.')
print(res.read())
res.close()`

But I think it's safer to use `subprocess.Popen()` instead of `os.popen()`.
[Here show how to switch over](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-popen-os-popen2-os-popen3)