# troubles when using a bash command inside a python script

Tags: python, bash

I am trying this on `python`:

```
import os

process="find . -type f -name *.out*.xyz'"
print "the number of xyz files is %s" %os.system(process)
```

When i try it from command line it works, but from python **it returns the number 0, when it is 4**. I think there must be a problem with the use of os.system. Any help?

Comment: Also check out the `subprocess` module. It's prefered over `os.system` these days.

Comment: And by "these days", we mean "since its release nearly 13 years ago".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes what you are getting is the return code "0" meaning "successfully completed, no errors" and not the stdout text output "4".

You should look here to get the output: [Assign output of os.system to a variable and prevent it from being displayed on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503879/assign-output-of-os-system-to-a-variable-and-prevent-it-from-being-displayed-on)

And here to learn about POSIX exit codes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you really just need the number of files in Python, try this:

```
import pathlib
p = pathlib.Path('.')
files = [x for x in p.iterdir() if x.is_file() and x.match('*.csv')]
print("Number of files: {0}".format(len(files)))
```

Easier, Pythonic and you do not need to fork a sub-process.