# How to search for string or line in os.system output

Tags: python

So I'm writing a simple socket program.  The client sends a directory path to the server.  'data' is the given directory path.  In the example below, it takes the path given and runs the Linux command 'ls -l path'.

```
        while True:
        print (data.decode())
        batcmd=('ls -l ' + data.decode())
        result = os.system(batcmd)
```

So if the client entered '/home/user', the shell command 'ls -l /home/user' will run and display the contents and permissions of the directory.

Now I want to sort through the result and fine a particular word.  Then display the line that contains that word.
For example, one line contains the word "Pictures".
So I want to display that line which is

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 myname myname 4096 Feb 25  2017 Pictures
```

If I try this:

```
import subprocess
import os
from socket import socket, gethostbyname, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM
import sys

PORT_NUMBER = 2000
SIZE = 1024

hostName = gethostbyname( '0.0.0.0' )

mySocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
mySocket.bind( (hostName, PORT_NUMBER) )

print ("Test server listening on port {0}\n".format(PORT_NUMBER))

# Receive no more than 1024 bytes


while True:
    (data,addr) = mySocket.recvfrom(SIZE)
    try:
        print >>sys.stderr, 'Received data from', addr
        while True:
            print (data.decode())
            batcmd=('ls -l ' + data.decode())
            result = os.system(batcmd)
            word = "Pictures"

            print result.find(word)

            # Do other stuff here
    finally:
        print >> sys.stderr, 'closing socket'
        sys.exit()
```

I get the error "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'find'"

If I try this:

```
import subprocess
import os
from socket import socket, gethostbyname, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM
import sys

PORT_NUMBER = 2000
SIZE = 1024

hostName = gethostbyname( '0.0.0.0' )

mySocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
mySocket.bind( (hostName, PORT_NUMBER) )

print ("Test server listening on port {0}\n".format(PORT_NUMBER))

# Receive no more than 1024 bytes


while True:
    (data,addr) = mySocket.recvfrom(SIZE)
    try:
        print >>sys.stderr, 'Received data from', addr
        while True:
            print (data.decode())
            batcmd=('ls -l ' + data.decode())
            result = os.system(batcmd)
            word = "pictures"

            for line in result:
                search_res = word(line)
                print line
                if search_res is None:
                    print ("That word does not exist.")
                break
            else:
                print ("something else")
            # Do other stuff

    finally:
        print >> sys.stderr, 'closing socket'
        sys.exit()
```

I get TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

What is the best way to go about finding a word and printing the line that word is contained in?

Do I need to dump result into a file in order to handle it?

Comment: `os.system()` returns the numeric exit code of the command, not the standard output.  See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503879/assign-output-of-os-system-to-a-variable-and-prevent-it-from-being-displayed-on .

Comment: Use this https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Comment: ah That explains it.

Comment: I am terrified of "receive UDP packets on port 2000 and execute them as shell commands" on so many levels.

Comment: lol I looked up the main use for port 2000 and see that a lot of trojans use it.  Is that why?  I'm just teaching myself socket programming and that was a random number I picked to run on my computer.