# Python // Pandas - Get json from API and turn into dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, get

I'm using this API to get companies data: https://github.com/vkruoso/receita-tools

Here you can see how the registry comes to me (which seems as a json structure): https://www.receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/27865757000102

I'm able to download it using the following:

```
cadastro = os.system("curl -X GET https://www.receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/27865757000102"
```

If I run `type(cadastro)` it shows up `class 'int'` to me.
I want to turn that into a dataframe. How could I do that?

Comment: What does it look like if you print it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`os.system` returns the exit code not the data. You should use subprocess instead, see [Assign output of os.system to a variable and prevent it from being displayed on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503879/assign-output-of-os-system-to-a-variable-and-prevent-it-from-being-displayed-on).

If you are using python 3.5+, you should use [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)

```
import subprocess
import json
import pandas as pd

proc = subprocess.run(["curl",  "-X", "GET",  
                  "https://www.receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/27865757000102"],
                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf-8')

cadastro = proc.stdout
df = pd.DataFrame([json.loads(cadastro)])
```

Otherwise, use `subprocess.Popen()`

```
import subprocess
import json
import pandas as pd

proc = subprocess.Popen(["curl",  "-X", "GET",  
                  "https://www.receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/27865757000102"],
                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

cadastro, err = proc.communicate()
df = pd.DataFrame([json.loads(cadastro)])
```

Or, you can use the [Requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get("https://www.receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/27865757000102")
data = json.loads(response.content.decode(response.encoding))
df = pd.DataFrame([data])
```

Comment: Tried using subprocess and it didn't work. Requests ran fine, but I will have to spend some time adjusting de data inside the dataframe.