# How to save AWS CLI command output to var in python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to save AWS CLI command into python variable (list). The trick is the following code returns result I want but doesn't save it into variable and return empty list.

```
import os
bashCommand = 'aws s3api list-buckets --query "Buckets[].Name"'
f = [os.system(bashCommand)]

print(f)
```

output:

```
[
"bucket1",
"bucket2",
"bucket3"
]
[0]
```

desired output:

```
[
"bucket1",
"bucket2",
"bucket3"
]
("bucket1", "bucket2", "bucket3")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign output of os.system to a variable and prevent it from being displayed on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503879/assign-output-of-os-system-to-a-variable-and-prevent-it-from-being-displayed-on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Python and you wish to list buckets, then it would be better to use the AWS SDK for Python, which is `boto3`:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
buckets = [bucket.name for bucket in s3.buckets.all()]
```

See: [S3 — Boto 3 Docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html)

This is much more sensible that calling out to the AWS CLI (which itself uses boto!).

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need anything fancy , all you have to do is import subprocess and json and use them :)

This was tested using python3.6 and on Linux

```
output = subprocess.run(["aws", "--region=us-west-2", "s3api", "list-buckets", "--query", "Buckets[].Name"],  stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

output_utf8=output.stdout.decode('utf-8')
output_utf8_json = json.loads(output_utf8)
print(output_utf8_json)

for key in output_utf8_json:
     print(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this command to create a Python list of all buckets:

```
bucket_list = eval(subprocess.check_output('aws s3api list-buckets --query "Buckets[].Name"').translate(None, '\r\n '))
```