# Reading string from terminal using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, gnome-terminal

I want to read the number of CPU from the terminal.

```
Number_of_process_to_run = int(input("Number of Process you want to run : "))
number_of_threads = (os.system("lscpu | grep 'CPU(s):' | head -1 | awk '{print $2}'"))

nt = int (input("Your Number of Threads is :" +str(number_of_threads)))
```

The number of threads which is grepped from os.system is not passing into the number of threads. It's taking a null value.

Comment: Also, in addition to @Tom Dalton's answer, you can simplify your life a little by using `os.system("nproc")` instead... https://askubuntu.com/questions/724228/how-to-find-the-number-of-cpu-cores-including-virtual for reference

Comment: It won't solve my problem, I am unable to store the value of os.system.

Answer (score 2):

Ref https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system

> ... the return value is the exit status of the process ...

The docs go on:

> The subprocess module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function.

Basically os.system doesn't allow you to capture the output of the subprocess you are running. You should have a look at `subprocess.run` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)

Comment: I need to capture the output, subprocess.run also won't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for misinterpreting the question before, but using `os.popen` should capture the number of processes, and as my comment mentioned, `nproc` also helps reduce the code:

```
Number_of_process_to_run = int(input("Number of Process you want to run : "))
number_of_threads = int((os.popen("nproc").read()))

print('Your Number of Threads is: ' + str(number_of_threads))
```

For more info about it this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503879/assign-output-of-os-system-to-a-variable-and-prevent-it-from-being-displayed-on) is very useful

Answer (score 1):

The `os.system()` function returns the exit code of the shell, not the output from the shell command that did the work. To capture this output, you need to open a pipe and read from it. The way to do this within the `os` module is to use `os.popen()` instead of `os.system()`

```
os.popen("""lscpu | grep 'CPU(s):' | head -1 | awk '{print $2}'""").read()
```

Another way is to use the newer `subprocess` module instead. Since `os.popen()` [has been depreciated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.popen) since version 2.6, you might prefer `subprocess`, especially if you expect your code to survive the next couple of Python revisions.

```
 subprocess.getoutput(""""lscpu | grep 'CPU(s):' | head -1 | awk '{print $2}'""")
```

Side note: My triple quotes may not be strictly necessary here, but I like to put them into such calls, just to make sure they don't interfere with any quotes inside of any shell commands.

Good luck!