# Why do I get a ValueError: could not convert string to float in Python?

Tags: python, string, floating-point, equation, valueerror

I do not understand why I get a ***ValueError*** when I want to transform a calcul *string* into *float*. I would like an issue because I am stuck up.

(The aim of my code is to create random equations with increasing level depending on question number.)(I am still a beginner, sorry if my code is unmethodical (and in french too).)

:)

There is my code:

(input)

```
from random import *

def Numéro_Question():
  global NuméroQuestion
  NuméroQuestion+=1
  print("\t~ Question {} ~\t\n".format(NuméroQuestion))

def Calcul2():
  PremierChiffre=randint(0, NuméroQuestion*5+5)
  Question=str(PremierChiffre)
  for i in range(1,NuméroQuestion+1): 
    SigneDeCalcul=["+","*","-"]
    SigneChoisi=str(choice(SigneDeCalcul))
    x=str(randint(0, NuméroQuestion*5+5))
    Question=Question+SigneChoisi+x
  print(type(Question))
  QuestionNumérique=float(QuestionNumérique)
  QuestionEcrite=Question+" = "
  Question=float
  Réponse=input(QuestionEcrite)


NuméroQuestion=0
Raté=0
while Raté<3:
  Numéro_Question()
  Calcul2()
  print("\n\n")
```

(output)

(The output changes each time you execute the program because it gives random number)

```
~ Question 1 ~

<class 'str'>
```

**Traceback (most recent call last):**

**File "main.py", ligne 26, in <module>**

**Calcul2()**

**File "mai,.py", ligne 17, in Calcul2**

**QuestionNumérique=float(QuestionNumérique)**
**ValueError: could not convert string to float: '3*6'**

Comment: Your string does not contain a representation of a float. Did you mean str(‘3.6’)?

Comment: `3*6` is not a floating point number.  It may be interpreted as an expression but `float()` only accepts floating point literal strings. Use something like `3.6`, or `18`, depending on what you want.

Comment: you want to convert an expression string `3*6` to a float. `*` is not a valid float character. Use the dangerous `eval` method

Comment: The code in the question does not produce that error. It actually raises `UnboundLocalError` because `QuestionNumérique` isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: @tom-karzes Please read the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval `ast.literal_eval` cannot evaluate simple operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because when you use `float(my_string)` it will only work if `my_string` can be cast as an actual float. It cannot do the multiplication for you.

Luckily, there is a very useful python function that accepts strings and runs them as code. It is called `eval`.

For example, `eval("12 + 3")` will return `15`.

Just use `eval` instead of `float`, like this:

```
QuestionNumérique=eval(QuestionNumérique)
```

In summary, you want to "evaluate" (`eval`) the Numeric Question, not to "cast" (`float`) it.

A caveat: As others point out, `eval` is "unsafe". In general, evaluating arbitrary strings as code is unsafe.

UPDATE: I was thinking about this while eating chips earlier and I had a *crazy* idea.

OK, so, in Python you can execute shell commands in a subprocess and pipe the results. (`os.popen` - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503879/assign-output-of-os-system-to-a-variable-and-prevent-it-from-being-displayed-on)) . Assuming the machine running python has Bash as its shell, we can use Bash's [arithmetic expression](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html) which (I think) might be easier to safeguard against arbitrary input.

Here is what it would look like:

```
import os

QuestionNumérique = "117 * 3 + 23 * 3"
shell_command = f"echo $(({QuestionNumérique}))"
piped_shell_result = os.popen(shell_command).read()
stripped_result = piped_shell_result.strip()
result_as_number = float(stripped_result)
```

**This code is still dangerous!** You would have to make sure the `QuestionNumérique` string contains "globally closed" `(` and `)` brackets, since someone could easily provide evil input like this:

```
QuestionNumérique = "117 * 3)); mkdir 'YOU HAVE BEEN H&CK3D'; echo $(("
```

If you can definitely make sure the input string has properly closed brackets then this should be safer than `eval`, since bash arithmetic expression will only do arithmetic.

Comment: Why is my answer being downvoted? Was that you, @tom-karzes? If so, can you please tell me why. I agree `eval` is unsafe but it is the only thing I know of in Python that can take an arbitrary algebraic expression and calculate the result. The OP wasn't asking for a safe alternative.  "Safely" evaluating arbitrary strings is a very very complicated subject, way beyond the scope of a single SO question.

Comment: You're right, I thought `ast.literal_eval` could handle expressions, but apparently it can't.  `eval` is still dangerous, and not something you want to use if it can be avoided.  And no, I didn't downvote your answer, it was someone else.  It was downvoted before I posted my first comment (which I've removed).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I wish people would explain why they downvote. It makes me want to remove my answer.

Comment: Some people will downvote any answer that uses `eval`.  I don't, but I will comment if I think `eval` can be avoided.

Comment: When a tool is forbidden, it makes me want to use that tool even more. Forbidden `eval`...

Comment: The really bad use case is when `eval` is used in some web server script to evaluate user input.  A malicious user can erase your files, delete your database, etc. by entering things like `os.system(...)`.

Comment: I completely agree with you. Web servers need to sanitize all user input. I added a comment to my answer saying how executing arbitrary strings is dangerous.
I look forward to seeing somebody provide an alternative solution.