# Translate youtube_dl command line into python .py file

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-dl

It's about how to get a list of URLs by using `youtube_dl`. Although I have been trying all day long, I couldn't work it out. Thus I would like to ask help to translate the following command lines (partially in Linux) into Python codes. I mean in a `.py` file.

1. To get JSON data, use command line: `youtube-dl -j --flat-playlist 'https://www.youtube.com/c/3blue1brown/videos'`
2. To parser use command line in Linux: `youtube-dl -j --flat-playlist 'https://www.youtube.com/c/3blue1brown/videos' | jq -r '.id' | sed 's_^_https://youtube.com/v/_'`

The codes above are from: https://web.archive.org/web/20180309061900/https://archive.zhimingwang.org/blog/2014-11-05-list-youtube-playlist-with-youtube-dl.html (The youtube link there was removed so I replaced the youtube link above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same command to run inside a .py file using os as follows:

```
import os
os.system("youtube-dl -j --flat-playlist 'https://www.youtube.com/c/3blue1brown/videos'")
```

You can pipe the output of the above commands to a file and then process your json file in python.

Comment: It's great! Thanks!

Comment: I just aware that the output of the os.system can only be seen on the console. Is there any methods to use the outputs direct in python? I would like to use the outputs for further codes. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503879/assign-output-of-os-system-to-a-variable-and-prevent-it-from-being-displayed-on

Comment: Or you can output the result of youtube-dl command to a file and then read from that file. e.g., `os.system("youtube-dl -j --flat-playlist 'https://www.youtube.com/c/3blue1brown/videos' > tempfile.txt")`