# How would I store the shell command output to a variable in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, shell, command

Code:

```
# cat mylinux.py
# This program is to interact with Linux

import os

v = os.system("cat /etc/redhat-release")
```

Output:

```
# python mylinux.py
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)
```

In the above output, the command output is displayed regardless of the variable I defined to store the output.

How to store the shell command output to a variable using os.system method only?

Comment: Why `os.system` only? To cite the documentation of `os.system`: "The `subprocess` module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function."

Comment: As @Mattias points out, `os.system()`  has been deprecated for decades. One of the many reasons why is because it does not do what you want. Insisting on a legacy function that doesn't do what you want, just because you don't want to learn about how to do properly, is not a good strategy for success.

Comment: os.sysetm is simple to use. Can you confirm if there are any ways to store the shell command output to a variable by using os module?

Comment: Let me get this right: You insist in using a possibly more complicated and less reliable way to get the output, just because you don't want to read "[Replacing Older Functions with the subprocess Module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements)"?

Comment: My intention is to use Python as an interpreter to communicate with your OS and execute any command you wish to run. If I want to use subprocess, I would need to split all such commands. That would make it more complicated.

Comment: May be you can use `os.popen`, but that's just a wild guess. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503879/assign-output-of-os-system-to-a-variable-and-prevent-it-from-being-displayed-on for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using module [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). It is included in Python's standard library and aims to be the substitute of `os.system`. (Note that the parameter `capture_output` of [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) was introduced in Python 3.7)

```py
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.run(['cat', '/etc/hostname'], capture_output=True)
CompletedProcess(args=['cat', '/etc/hostname'], returncode=0, stdout='example.com\n', stderr=b'')
>>> subprocess.run(['cat', '/etc/hostname'], capture_output=True).stdout.decode()
'example.com\n'
```

In your case, just:

```py
import subprocess

v = subprocess.run(['cat', '/etc/redhat-release'], capture_output=True).stdout.decode()
```

Update: you can split the shell command easily with [`shlex.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) provided by the standard library.

```
>>> import shlex
>>> shlex.split('cat /etc/redhat-release')
['cat', '/etc/redhat-release']
>>> subprocess.run(shlex.split('cat /etc/hostname'), capture_output=True).stdout.decode()
'example.com\n'
```

Update 2: [`os.popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.popen) mentioned by @Matthias

However, is is impossible for this function to separate stdout and stderr.

```py
import os

v = os.popen('cat /etc/redhat-release').read()
```

Comment: This is bit complex. I am looking for a simpler step. I prefer to use os module instead of subprocess where I don't need to split everything into sub processes.

Comment: @SachinAravind In your case, `v = open('/etc/redhat-release').read()` is the simplest way.

Comment: Thanks. But my intention is to make Python as an interpreter to communicate with your OS and execute any command that end user prefers, that too in real time.

Comment: @SachinAravind All right, but, just as a reminder, remember to check if the command entered by user is safe before execution. DO NOT trust user input all the time.

Comment: Even this code is not working:

# cat mylinux.py

import subprocess
import shlex

subprocess.run(shlex.split(input("Enter the command:")),capture_output=True).stdout.decode()

Output:
# python mylinux.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mylinux.py", line 13, in <module>
    subprocess.run(shlex.split(input("Enter the command:")),capture_output=True).stdout.decode()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run'

Comment: Even the below code is not working.

v=subprocess.check_output(shlex.split("ls -lrt"),stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
v.stdout

Comment: This is the error:

v=subprocess.check_output(shlex.split("ls -lrt"),stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 567, in check_output
    raise ValueError('stdout argument not allowed, it will be overridden.')
ValueError: stdout argument not allowed, it will be overridden.

Comment: @SachinAravind You should NOT use Python 2.7 any more since it reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020! It has been deprecated for more than 2 years. See https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/

Comment: Even in Python 3.6, I am getting below error.

[root@bteir python_exercise]# python mylinux.py
This is an interactive linux session using Python!
Here if you want to exit the session, type exit as the input command
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mylinux.py", line 13, in <module>
    v=subprocess.check_output(shlex.split("ls -lrt"),stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 348, in check_output
    raise ValueError('stdout argument not allowed, it will be overridden.')
ValueError: stdout argument not allowed, it will be overridden.

Comment: @SachinAravind Yes, you're right. As I mentioned, `capture_out` was introduced in Python 3.7. In version below that you can use `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` instead.

Comment: Can you specify the alteration to be made?
v=subprocess.check_output(shlex.split("ls -lrt"),stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
v.stdout

Comment: @SachinAravind `subprocess.check_output` does not need parameter `stdout` but `subprocess.run` does. Both `subprocess.check_output(shlex.split("ls -lrt")).decode()` and `subprocess.run(shlex.split("ls -lrt"), stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode()` work fine on my Python 3.6

Comment: Thanks. This works!
`v=subprocess.run(shlex.split("ls -lrt"), stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode()
print(v)`

Comment: @SachinAravind Congratulations!

Comment: In case if the shell is changing or if I am switching to some other user, the script ceases the execution. Is there any way I can make the script executes completely?

Comment: And also for the below command, 
`echo "this is the command execution" >> hi`
it is just giving the output as follow, instead of appending the echo output to the file hi.
`this is the command execution >> hi`

Comment: @SachinAravind Use `subprocess.run(['sh', '-c', 'echo "this is the command execution" >> hi'], ...)` instead of `shlex`. `>>` is a part of the syntax of bash-like shells.