# Find and delete oldest AVI file recursively

Tags: ruby

I've been trying to write a Ruby script to find and delete the oldest AVI file in a folder.  I found a [script in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837606/find-the-oldest-file-recursively-in-a-directory/837840#837840) that is very close, and I got a good start on the Ruby solution myself with:

```
require 'fileutils'
stat = Sys::Filesystem.stat("/")
mb_available = stat.block_size * stat.blocks_available / 1024 / 1024
#if there is less than 130MB free
if mb_available < 130000
    require 'find'
    movie_file_paths = []
    #grab all the files in the folder
    Find.find('/Users/jody/Movies') do |path|
        movie_file_paths << path if /.*\.avi/.match(path) != nil
    end
end
```

But, I'm having a tough time with the rest.  Any help would be appreciated!

---

EDIT:

This was the solution:

```
movie_file_paths = []
Dir.glob("/Users/jody/Movies/**/*.avi").each { |file| movie_file_paths << file if File.file? file }
movie_file_paths.sort_by {|f| File.mtime(f)}
deleteme = movie_file_paths.first
```

Comment: I just saw your solution; `movie_file_paths.sort_by {|f| File.mtime(f)}` does *NOT* modify the `movie_file_paths` array. It returns a new sorted array. 

You should do:
`movies = movie_file_paths.sort_by {|f| File.mtime(f)}`
`deleteme = movies.first`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `File.mtime(filename)` to get the last modified time of the file.

`movie_file_path.sort_by {|f| File.mtime(f)}` will return a sorted array by `mtime`. You can then delete the file using `File.delete(filename)`.

Edit: Last accessed time `atime` might be a better option than `mtime`.

Comment: I get NameError: undefined local variable or method `movie_file_path' for main:Object when I try to run this at the end of my routine

Answer (score 3):

I see you've already selected an answer but it can be a one-liner:

```
File.delete(Dir.glob("/Users/jody/Movies/**/*.avi").sort_by{|f| File.mtime(f)}.first)
```

Update: I came across this a few years later and thought to myself, "I can make that shorter!"

```
File.delete(Dir["/Users/jody/Movies/**/*.avi"]).min_by{|f| File.mtime(f)})
```

Answer (score 2):

[`File`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html) has the methods you want, specifically `ctime` for "last changed" times (creation times on NTFS), `mtime` if you want "last modified" times, or `atime` for "last accessed" times. Combining this with `Dir::glob`, you can easily get a list of files sorted by datetime:

```
videos = Dir['/Users/jody/Movies/*.avi'].sort_by(&:ctime)
```

Deleting the last one is very simple:

```
File.delete videos.last
```

Comment: `Dir['/Users/jody/Movies/*.avi'].min_by(&:ctime)` is simpler.

Comment: Thanks.  Neither of these would be recursive though right and therefore wouldn't get any of the subfolders?

Comment: "ctime for creation times". Only Windows NTSF stores a creation time for files, otherwise, for other OSes it's the change time.