# Moving oldest file names with different extensions to common folder. Python

Tags: python

I have a folder that contains 15 .jpg files and 15 .pdf files. The file names are the same with just the extensions being different. Example ABC123.jpg and ABC123.pdf. I have spent the better part of the last few days trying to use shutil to move the oldest .pdf file to a new folder then finding the matching .jpg file and moving it to the same folder as the .pdf. I was able to move the oldest file or move all files of a given type. Just couldn't get the oldest of a specific type. I tried moving all .pdfs to a new folder1 and all .jpgs to a new folder2 and then moving oldest from each of those to a common folder. However, they don't always match. The oldest .jpg might be different than the oldest .pdf. I am sure there is a simple solution, I have just been working it in circles so long I can no longer see the forest through the trees.

Comment: Please post the code that you need help with. See How to [Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `os.path.getmtime` function as the key to sort your files.

```
import os
def oldest_file(dir, type):
    return min([name for name in os.listdir(dir) if name.endswith(type)], key=lambda name: os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(dir, name)))
print(oldest('/your/folder', '.jpg'))
```

If you need to search the entire tree, use `os.walk` instead of `os.listdir`:

```
import os
from itertools import chain
def oldest_file(dir, type):
    return min(list(chain(*[[os.path.join(root, file) for file in files if file.endswith(type)] for root, _, files in os.walk(dir)])), key=lambda file: os.path.getmtime(file))
print(oldest('/your/folder', '.jpg'))
```

I'm sure you can handle the rest of the code that deals with moving files.

Answer (score 0):

I found `oldest_file_in_tree` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837606/find-the-oldest-file-recursively-in-a-directory).

```
import os
import shutil

def oldest_file_in_tree(rootfolder, extension=".avi"):
    return min(
        (os.path.join(dirname, filename)
        for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rootfolder)
        for filename in filenames
        if filename.endswith(extension)),
        key=lambda fn: os.stat(fn).st_mtime)

oldest_pdf = oldest_file_in_tree('/var/somedir', '.pdf')
name = oldest_pdf[:4]
matching_jpg = '{}.jpg'.format(name)

shutil.move("/var/somedir/{}.pdf".format(name), "path/to/new/destination/{}.pdf".format(name))
shutil.move("/var/somedir/{}.jpg".format(name), "path/to/new/destination/{}.jpg".format(name))
```

Comment: At first this did not work. I was receiving trace back errors. I changed the code a little and was able to get it to work.

Comment: @user9679329 Thanks for the feedback. What changes did you make? I will update the answer. If this answer was correct would you consider marking at as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I was able to make it work..

```
import os, shutil
import glob

todir = '/var/somedir/'
def oldest_file_in_tree(rootfolder, extension=".pdf"):
    return min(
        (os.path.join(dirname, filename)
        for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rootfolder)
        for filename in filenames
        if filename.endswith(extension)),
        key=lambda fn: os.stat(fn).st_mtime)

oldest_g3d = oldest_file_in_tree('/var/somedir/', '.pdf')
name = oldest_pdf[:-4]
matching_jpg = '{}.jpg'.format(name)

shutil.move(oldest_pdf, todir)
shutil.move(matching_jpg, todir)
```